# Life is a healthy respect for mother nature laced with greed

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idioms

I read such a quote from command line utility fortune

> `$ fortune`
>   `Life is a healthy respect for mother nature laced with greed.`

Does that sentence mean that we are greedy to live long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems more a cynical observation than anything truly meaningful.  I guess it means that life is driven by *fear* and *desire* -- fear of what natural forces can do to us, combined with the desire to control those forces as much as possible.

But this assumes it's only talking about *human* life, which could have been explicitly stated.  In any case, as an aphorism, it's not particularly witty or well-written.  Why not just say something like:

> Life is the futile struggle between *fear* and *greed*.